# Webpack serve doesn't reload upon file changes

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

first time writing on Stack please don't be too harsh on me.

I'm currently experiencing problems with webpack dev server (webpack serve NOT webpack-dev-server). Changes to my files are seen by Webpack (it shows compiling every time i save my files) but the actual pages don't change at all.

For example changing my HTML files won't be displayed unless i manually reload the page (no live reloading) but changes to my .js files won't be recognized by the server unless i completely close the service and restart it.

I'm working on a simple HTML page with a literally two .js files and a couple of .css

Here's my package.json

```
  "name": "s2i-pullution",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "To correctly make the project run it's needed to have a personal Token for the AQICN API,",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --watch --progress",
    "dev": "webpack serve --hot --inline"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://gitlab.com/gp1108/s2i-weather.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://gitlab.com/gp1108/s2i-weather/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://gitlab.com/gp1108/s2i-weather#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv-webpack": "^6.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.21.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

Here's the webpack.config.js

```
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './public/scripts/search.js',
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv(),
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname,'public/dist/'),
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './public/',
    port: 8000,
  },
  watchOptions: {
    poll:500,
  },
};
```

Here's my project structure:

```
|s2i-pollution (main folder)
|---|webpack.config.js
|---|package.json
|---|package-lock.json
|---|node_modules (folder)
|---|.env
|---|public (folder)
|-----|index.html
|-----|city.html
|-----|images (folder)
|-----|styles (folder)
|-----|scripts
|-------|search.js
|-------|theme-chooser.js
|-----|dist (folder)
|-------|main.js
```

I've imported theme-chooser.js into search.js with this line of code:
`import './theme-chooser.js';`

I'm currently using Xubuntu 20.04 LTS.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you see the message `[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...` in the browser's console, when you open your application, but not the messages `[WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.` and `[WDS] Live Reloading enabled.`, then you could try and add the parameter `target: 'web'` to your `webpack.config.js` like so:

```
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './public/scripts/search.js',
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv(),
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname,'public/dist/'),
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './public/',
    port: 8000,
  },
  watchOptions: {
    poll:500,
  },
  target: 'web',
};
```

Also, make sure that you have the following three lines of code in your search.js file:

```
if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept();
}
```

For additional information you can look here: [Hot Module Replacement | Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/)